# How to solve problem "The chunk size cannot be larger"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am making a small application, but after posting to the server, any internal error results in:

> stream_set_chunk_size(): The chunk size cannot be larger than 2147483647

I also see that no information is being written to the "laravel.log" file. Everything works correctly on the local machine

I checked the memory_limit in my php.ini and the paths and permissions to the "laravel.log" file are correct. I use Laravel 8 and php 7.4

What could be the problem?

[image]

I created a get route "/callback" with one single logging method for testing. On the local machine, the log was written, on the server - it gave the same error "stream_set_chunk_size(): The chunk size cannot be larger than 2147483647"

```
public function callback(Request $request)
{
  Log::info('Hello!');
  die();
}
```

If I change LOG_LEVEL in my ENV to anything other than "debug" - I can see an error in the browser, but I also want to write to the Log

Comment: probably the `post` you want to send to server is so huge!?

Comment: Hi @John, I created a route / callback with one single logging method for testing. On the local machine, the log was written, on the server - it gave the same error "stream_set_chunk_size(): The chunk size cannot be larger than 2147483647":

Comment: put this on top of your function , `ini_set('memory_limit','80M');` and see if its working.
the only thing i can say is memory limit .

Comment: But memory_limit in php.ini is unlimited =)

Comment: can you see the first your running code (not the vendors) before `logger.php` ? in the laravel error page you provided the screen shot.